# How to make all screens consistent in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, screen

I wrote game code and played, using iPhone 6 Plus simulator, and it is working fine, but once I switch to other devices, UI is messed up... I do not want to do this from scratch. Is there any way to fix this problem by, for example, adding some code...? I thought about adding `UIScreen` but I do not know how to do that. If you could give me some advice, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach to implementing user interfaces for multiple screen dimensions is to use auto layout.  You should read [Apple's guide to auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).